# Instance of class that closes a generic interface not implicitly castable to member of generic interface type

Tags: c#, generics

I have researched this quite a bit on SO and Google. My C# app needs to be able to handle results of type long, decimal, and float. I've been exploring the option of making a generic interface, then closing it for each result type.

Here is the sample code:

```
using System;

interface IResult<T>
{
    T Result();
    void Increment(T value);
}

public class ResultLong : IResult<long>
{
    private long result;

    public long Result()
    {
        return result;
    }

    public void Increment(long value)
    {
        result += value;
    }
}

public class App<T> where T : IConvertible
{
    private IResult<T> result;

    public void Run()
    {
        result = new ResultLong();
    }
}
```

This gives the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'ResultLong' to 'IResult'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Adding a cast fixes the compiler error, but then the Increment method throws:

> Cannot convert from int to T.

```
public void Run()
{
    result = (IResult<T>)new ResultLong();
    result.Increment(500);
}
```

Please let me know if this overall approach is valid, and if so, how I might make it work. If it's an invalid approach, what do you recommend?

Thanks!
Aron

I should also mention, this is how I'm currently handling it:

```
using System;
public class Result
{
    public long ResultLong { get; set; }
    public decimal ResultDecimal { get; set; }
    public double ResultFloat { get; set; }
    public DateTime ResultDateTime { get; set; }

    public void Increment<T>(T value) where T : IConvertible
    {
        if (value is int || value is long)
        {
            ResultLong += value.ToInt64(null);
        }
        else if (value is decimal)
        {
            ResultDecimal += value.ToDecimal(null);
        }
        else if (value is double)
        {
            ResultFloat += value.ToDouble(null);
        }
        else if (value is DateTime)
        {
            ResultDateTime = value.ToDateTime(null);
        }
    }
}
```

And I should further mention that after looking into the suggestions, I decided to go with basic method overloading, and the app seems to be working fine so far.

```
public void Increment(int value)
{
    ResultLong += value;
}
public void Increment(long value)
{
    ResultLong += value;
}

public void Increment(double value)
{
    ResultDouble += value;
}

public void Increment(decimal value)
{
    ResultDecimal += value;
}

public void Increment(DateTime value)
{
    ResultDateTime = value;
}
```

S.O. has been my primary guide in getting over many hurdles in learning C#. This was my first question and I greatly appreciate everyone's responses.

Comment: In `App<T>`, `T` isn't necessarily `long`. It could as easily be `decimal`, or `Boolean`. A general way to attack similar problems (never very nice, and possibly unusable in your specific case) would be to derive `IResult<T>` from a non-generic `IResult`, and use that in `App<T>`. Or write a concrete `Result<T>` class implementing `IResult<T>`, then do `public void Run() { result = new Result<T>; }` -- but only if both `T`s are the same `T`; not clear if that's so.

Comment: Please check Factory method design pattern for `Run()` ;).

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'll research your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ResultLong is `IResult<long>` and not `IResult<T>`, so you get the error message.

Since you are insisting on using `long`, there really is no need for the generic type syntax (because you already know what the type is).

```
public class App 
{
    private IResult<long> result;

    public void Run()
    {
        result = new ResultLong();
        result.Increment(500);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it could also be decimal or double. In those cases I'd want to instantiate via `result = new ResultDecimal();` or `result = new ResultDouble();` and then  call `result.Increment()`, passing in a value of the respective type.